# How to run php script from webserver with user permission

Tags: php, bash

I've done this script :

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php


system('whoami');
```

This script does belong to userName.

When I run it from a webbrowser, using the following php script:

```
<?php
$cmd = 'php -f "/pathtomy/programm/whoami.php"';
system($cmd);
```

it output _www
( I'm on a mac ).

I would like the script to output userName,
when called from the webbrowser.

Is this possible ?
I saw c++ wrapper solution on this forum,
but I don't have the time to learn c++ yet,
so I wondered if there were other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user the web server is running as (`_www`) is the user as which any and all scripts will execute. If you want to switch to a different user, you can use `su` or similar mechanisms to switch users in the command you're executing, but that also means `_www` will have to have permissions set up to be able to switch to that user. It's also generally a bad idea to execute anything as another user, the web server is specifically running as `_www`, which should have very very limited permissions on the system, to minimize security breaches.

There's probably a better solution to do what you want to do which does not require you to switch users.